# AVD dont Work on my W7 pc

Tags: android-emulator

I'd like to run my sdk Emulator on my Windows7 PC
I made a emulator but I get always this error:

> emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
>   Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

But all paths are correct.

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to help you. Follow its suggestion and try re-creating, or reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using win7 and I have no problem. The config.ini and other files for AVD are actually located on

> c:\Users*your_username*.android.

However, I think maybe you are running the shell command to create the AVD? If so, maybe you should change the path where you run it. If you path to run the shell command contains whitespace or non-ascii character, you might see the error message. Classic Windows path problems.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Beginners/2009-09/msg01449.html) is what you should do if you have this problem - create a custom avd by this type of command:

> android create avd -n my_avd -t 1 -p f:\avd

Customize it accordingly and answer the prompted questions after entering this command.